# Peek fails with uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why does the peek gem show `uninitialized constant Peek::Views::Mysql2 (NameError)`. Followed the steps as in the documentation https://github.com/peek/peek. Addedmount Peek::Railtie => '/peek'

```
  root :to => 'home#show'
```

Gem is present in the local gemset as well

```
config/initializers/peek.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Peek::Views::Mysql2 (NameError)
        from /home/pris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@ybp/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
        from /home/pris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@ybp/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
        from /home/pris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@ybp/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
        from /home/pris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@ybp/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from /home/pris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@ybp/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
        from /home/pris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@ybp/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from /home/pris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@ybp/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/pris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@ybp/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/pris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@ybp/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the [`peek-mysql2` gem](https://github.com/peek/peek-mysql2) as well in your Gemfile.

For each `Peek.into ...` statement in the `config/initializers/peek.rb` file, the [corresponding gem containing the view files](https://github.com/peek/peek/tree/master#available-peek-views) should be included.